# How to make an event which gets triggered in another class

Tags: c#, events, event-handling

In my code for the PluginManager the event *PluginEvent* gets triggered after
a plugin has been added. But I want to get the event also triggered in the **test class**.
Somehow I cant solve this problem. The event only gets triggered in the **PluginManager class**. I read some articles how to create events and so on, but I got even more confused

---

**PluginManager class**

```
public class PluginEventArgs
{
    public PluginEventArgs(string s) { Text = s; }
    public String Text { get; private set; } // readonly
}

public class PluginManager
{
    // Declare the delegate (if using non-generic pattern).
    public delegate void PluginEventHandler(object sender, PluginEventArgs e);

    // Declare the event.
    public event PluginEventHandler PluginEvent;

    protected virtual void RaiseSampleEvent(string message)
    {
        if (PluginEvent != null)
        PluginEvent(this, new PluginEventArgs(message));
    }


    public PluginManager()
    {
        PluginEvent += PluginManager_PluginEvent;
        SomeMethod();
    }

    void PluginManager_PluginEvent(object sender, PluginEventArgs e)
    {
       //This event gets triggered =)
    }

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        //Code
        RaiseSampleEvent("Name of the Plugin");
        //Code
    }


 }
```

**My test class:**

```
class test
{
    public test()
    {
        PluginManager pluginMg = new PluginManager();

        pluginMg.PluginEvent += pluginMg_PluginEvent;
    }

    //I want this event to get triggered when a new plugin has been found
    void pluginMg_PluginEvent(object sender, PluginEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Text);
    }

}
```

---

How can I manage to get the event triggered in the **test class**?
Thanks for any advise!

Comment: Always keep ctor light and never raise non-static events from ctor, else it will be useless for caller class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're actually doing things right except for one logical Mistake.

In your test class you're creating the PluginManager by using the constructor. The constructor of PluginManager first subscribes to the event and then raises it.

AFTERWARDS you're subscribing to that event.

The simple Problem is that when you are raising the event your test class has not subscribed yet. When you raise that event again everything should work out just fine.

Another thing is that I would use the generic EventHandler class instead of creating your own delegates. This keeps your code cleaner and everyone knows that this is meant to be an event at first glance.

Just inherit PlugInEventArgs from EventArgs and then use EventHandler.

Comment: Awww that mistake just got me for 2 hours :3. Thank you for your advise, I gonna use the generic EventHandler class.

Comment: +1 for Encouraging to utilize **Generic EventHandler class**.

Answer (score 1):

In your PluginManager class you shouldn't subscribe to your own event PluginEvent, you should subscribe to an external event or just raise the PluginEvent.
Let me give you an example:

```
public class PluginEventArgs
{
    public PluginEventArgs(string s) { Text = s; }
    public String Text { get; private set; } // readonly
}

public class OtherClass
{
    public event PluginEventHandler PluginEvent;

    private void RaiseEvent()
    {
        if (null != PluginEvent)
            PluginEvent(this, new PluginEventArgs("some message"));
    }
}

public delegate void PluginEventHandler(object sender, PluginEventArgs e);

public class PluginManager
{

    public event PluginEventHandler PluginEvent;

    private OtherClass otherClass;

    protected virtual void RaiseSampleEvent(string message)
    {
        if (PluginEvent != null)
            PluginEvent(this, new PluginEventArgs(message));
    }

    public PluginManager(OtherClass otherClass)
    {
        this.otherClass = otherClass;
        this.otherClass.PluginEvent += otherClass_PluginEvent;
        SomeMethod();
    }

    void otherClass_PluginEvent(object sender, PluginEventArgs e)
    {
        if (PluginEvent != null)
            PluginEvent(sender, e); // this way the original sender and args are transferred.
    }

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        //Code
        RaiseSampleEvent("Name of the Plugin");
        //Code
    }


}

class test
{
    public test()
    {
        OtherClass otherClass = new OtherClass();
        PluginManager pluginMg = new PluginManager(otherClass);

        pluginMg.PluginEvent += pluginMg_PluginEvent;
    }

    //I want this event to get triggered when a new plugin has been found
    void pluginMg_PluginEvent(object sender, PluginEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Text);
    }

}
```